# Rails ajax not returning json format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to use ajax to get information from my controller.

But it's not returning the json as I expect. Maybe I'ts a routing conflict, but not sure.

My controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :js, :json, :html
  //...
  def fill_category_select
    @category_by_system = Category.where(system_id: params[:sent_id])
    render json: @category_by_system
  end
```

my routes.rb:

```
  resources :tickets

  get 'tickets/fill_category_select/:sent_id', to: 'tickets#fill_category_select'
```

my script on a haml file:

```
:javascript
      $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#ticket_system').change(function(){
          $.ajax({
                  url: "fill_category_select", 
                 type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
                 data: { sent_id:   $('#ticket_system').val() },
                 async: true,
              success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                         for(var i in data){
                           var id = data[i].id;
                           var title = data[i].description;
                           $("#ticket_category").append(new Option(title, id));
                         }
                       },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorTextStatus, error){
                        alert("Failed: "+ errorTextStatus+" ;"+error);
                     }
            });
          });
        });
```

When I trigger the event and do the request it is:

> REQUEST URL:
>   http://localhost:3000/tickets/fill_category_select?sent_id=44
>
> REQUEST METHOD: GET
>
> STATUS CODE: 200 OK
>
> TYPE: html

And the error returned and displayed the javascript alert is: *"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"*

It's like not hiting my fill_category_select, cause i've tried to put a raise 'error' and it just show the same error.

Does anyone can give me a direction?

---------- EDIT

I found the route line is not working.

when I add   resources :tickets , except: [:show]

The request bring to me a "404 error", it's not simply an override problem, routing is not working at all.

And I still need to discovery what Im doing wrong. any suggestion?

Comment: If you append the url with **.json** to force it in JSON format, will it work ? For example: **fill_category_select.json**.

Comment: Yes, even when I put .json in my request, the response is still in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
  match 'tickets/fill_category_select/:sent_id' => 'tickets#fill_category_select', via: :get
```

for route my method fill_category_select

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.rb file, please replace existing one with this.

```
 get 'tickets/fill_category_select/:sent_id' => 'tickets#fill_category_select', defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

This will work i think

Comment: still bring the Tickets#show html response, and not hitting my method :[

Comment: okay in the script, where you have written url: "fill_category_select", change this to url: "/tickets/fill_category_select"

Comment: i think previously it was going to show action in tickets controller. but lets see if my above comments make sense.

Comment: okay... i was hoping that should work. there is one more thing we can try. as our route expect thing like this 'tickets/fill_category_select/:sent_id', can we try this please var path = '/tickets/', #nextline path += '/fill_category_select', #nextline path = $('#ticket_system').val(), #nextline url: path,

Comment: with minor fix
 var path = '/tickets/', #nextline path += '/fill_category_select', #nextline path+ = $('#ticket_system').val(), #nextline url: path,

Comment: still the same error, I'm adding an update in the thread description.

Comment: please if you can update your code above with changes i can have a look at them.

Comment: You mean:

      path = '/tickets/';
      path += '/fill_category_select';
      path += $('#ticket_system').val();

      $.ajax({
              url: path, // Route to the Script Controller method

Comment: yes you shall make the url like this: url: "/tickets/fill_category_select/123" so take a variable path and make a string like i stated above and use that as url.

Comment: well, its almost 3 a.m in brazil, tomorrow I will continue this. thank you.